# "gem install bundler --version=0.8.1" doesn't install the bundle executable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, rubygems, bundler

When trying to install Bundler 0.8.1 on Ubuntu machine, it install fine but the executable "bundle" is no where to be seen. Other gems install successfully, including their executables.

using: `gem install bundler --version=0.8.1`

```
RubyGems Environment:
- RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.3.7
- RUBY VERSION: 1.8.7 (2009-06-12 patchlevel 174) [i486-linux]
- INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /home/ahammad/gems
- RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/ruby1.8
- EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /home/ahammad/gems/bin
- RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
- ruby
- x86-linux
- GEM PATHS:
 - /home/ahammad/gems
- GEM CONFIGURATION:
 - :update_sources => true
 - :verbose => true
 - :benchmark => false
 - :backtrace => false
 - :bulk_threshold => 1000
 - :sources => ["http://gems.rubyforge.org/", "http://gem1.gilt.com"]
- REMOTE SOURCES:
 - http://gems.rubyforge.org/
```

Path `/home/ahammad/gems/bin` has been added to `PATH`, the problem is there is no bundle exe.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

apparently 0.8.1 uses "gem bundle" rather than "bundle"

Answer (score 9):

Maybe that specific version of bundler wasn't available for installation, so to choose specific available range of versions which could be available, try:

```
gem install bundler --version '<= 0.10.6'
```

Or simple uninstall the previous bundler and install it again. Then check by `gem list bundler` or `bundler _0.9.26_ -v` (where `0.9.26` is version of your older gem).

Check also the permissions of your local gem folders.

Learn more: [How to upgrade/downgrade Rubygems](http://rubygems.rubyforge.org/rubygems-update/UPGRADING_rdoc.html) at rubyforge

Answer (score 0):

That might be. I've used only 1.0. But I had the same problem. A tutorial assumed I could run "bundle". It was fixed only after following the directions here 
 http://lindsaar.net/2010/3/31/bundle_me_some_sanity
The directions involve installing rvm and creating an app directory with a .rvmrc file among other things.
Then in that directory you can run "bundle".
The binary is ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302@railsplugins/bin/bundle